Snowflake error, Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
I have a user defined function which returns number, argument is also a number. There is an aggregate function(sum()) inside the UDF. I am calling this UDF from a select clause. It's giving me the error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated".
Basically i am rewriting the query used in SQL server DB. But it seems like snowflake doesn't support this case as it is. How can i rewrite it for snowflake?
The queries loos like:
Query:
select salesNumber, date , totalValue(SalesId)  
from salesTable

totalValue UDF body:
select  sum(amount) 
from SalesItems 
where SalesId=parameter_salesId


display a sample output and a minimum amount of reproducible code.

Added a sample query

@Srekanth can you please add the code for the function that you written.

Yes, it is a correlated subquery and they perform badly, so write it better, the simpler way would be:
with as_cte as 
(
   select 
      SalesId, 
      sum(amount) as s_amount
   from SalesItems
   group by 1
)
select 
    st.salesNumber, 
    st.date, 
    c.s_amount
from salesTable as st
join as_cte as c
  on c.SalesId = st.parameter_salesId

If you have large tables that CTE would benefit from having filters added to it.
A horrible (for large table performance) way would be:
select 
    st.salesNumber, 
    st.date, 
    sum(si.amount) as s_amount
from salesTable as st
join SalesItems as si
  on si.SalesId = st.parameter_salesId
group by 1


I am rewriting SQL Server query for snowflake. I have to use UDF  otherwise i have to rewrite lot of queries. Not much worried about performance, as it use once in a while. Is there a way to use UDF instead of CTE?
